# Change moment.js locale on the fly in Angular 8

Tags: angular, momentjs, locale

**THE TITLE** is what I need. I have a language picker drop down in my app and so far I've been using it to dynamically (without refreshing the page) change the language in the app. When I tried to do that using moment.js' `moment.locale(string)`, it doesn't update the view like the rest of the app.

```
setLocale(locale?: string) {
    if (!locale) locale = localStorage.getItem("locale") || "en-US";
    localStorage.setItem("locale", locale);
    this.adapter.setLocale(locale); //for date picker (nothing to do with moment.js)
    moment.locale(locale); // for moment.js ------------------- only works after refresh
    this.translate.use(locale); //rest of the app
}
```

That's the method invoked when a language is selected from the drop down, but dates rendered by moment.js are not updated but until page refresh.

Is there a way to do this? Hack? Workaround?

Thanks

Comment: Try [this](https://github.com/urish/ngx-moment/issues/126#issuecomment-391630148).

Answer (score 0):

```js
@Pipe({
  name: 'dynamicMoment'
})
export class MomentPipe implements PipeTransform {
  /**
   * MomentPipe constructor
   * @param {TranslateService} translate
   */
  constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {
  }

  /**
   * Make moment dynamic
   * @param {string} value
   * @param {string} format
   * @returns {any}
   */
  transform(value: string, format?: string): any {
    // make the moment format configurable
    format = format ? format : 'MMMM Do YYYY';
    // get the initial value
    const initVal = moment(value).locale(moment.locale()).format(format);
    // insert the value into a new behaviour subject. If the language changes, the behaviour subject will be 
    // updated
    const momentObs = new BehaviorSubject<string>(initVal);
    this.translate.onLangChange.subscribe(() => {
      // format the new date according to the new locale
      const val = moment(value).locale(moment.locale()).format(format);
      momentObs.next(val);
    });
    return momentObs; // needs to be piped into the async pipe
  }

}
```